# Perl Modules "run" command

Tags: perl

I'm using the Perl tool Cluster SSH tool (cssh).
In the main part this code:

```
    use App::ClusterSSH;
    
    my $app = App::ClusterSSH->new();
    
    $app->options->add_common_ssh_options;
    $app->options->add_common_session_options;
    $app->run();
```

There is this directory for perl modules of this tool:
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26.1/App/ClusterSSH

An `ls` of this directory shows:

```
   Base.pm  Cluster.pm  Config.pm  Getopt.pm  Helper.pm  Helper.pm.orig  Host.pm  L10N  L10N.pm  Range.pm  Window  Window.pm
   ./L10N:
   en.pm
   ./Window:
   Tk.pm
```

Question

1. I cannot find a subroutine for "run" in the perl modules for the tool. If there is no sub called "run" what does the command do:

   $app->run()
2. I do not understand what this means:

   $app->options->add_common_ssh_options;

There is an sub in Base.pm called options

There is an sub called add_common_ssh_options in another file called Getopt.pm

I think that:

```
$app->options
```

would call the sub options but what does the additional arrow function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [subroutine named run](https://metacpan.org/release/DUNCS/App-ClusterSSH-4.16/source/lib/App/ClusterSSH.pm#L302) in [App::ClusterSSH](https://metacpan.org/dist/App-ClusterSSH).

The `$app->options->add_common_ssh_options` is you calling the method `options` on `$app`, then calling the method `add_common_ssh_options` on the return value from `options`. This is typically called "method chaining". It's the same as doing it in two statements:

```
my $options = $app->options;
$options->add_common_ssh_options;
```